# Trying to split out a character from a bash "list"

Tags: python

So I have this command that runs the following report in your shell;

```
Command output 
Available Reports for: isl-01-chi Time Zone: CDT
================================================================================
|ID       |FSA Job Start              |FSA Job End                |Size        |
================================================================================
|313      |Aug 21 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 22 2016, 12:33 AM      |1.040G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|318      |Aug 22 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 23 2016, 12:35 AM      |1.039G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|323      |Aug 23 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 24 2016, 12:34 AM      |1.045G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|328      |Aug 24 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 25 2016, 12:35 AM      |1.043G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|333      |Aug 25 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 26 2016, 12:57 AM      |1.057G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|339      |Aug 26 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 27 2016, 03:01 AM      |2.183G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|346      |Aug 28 2016, 07:24 AM      |Aug 28 2016, 11:53 AM      |2.183G      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|351      |Aug 28 2016, 10:00 PM      |Aug 29 2016, 02:37 AM      |2.182G      |
================================================================================
```

What I'm looking to do is find the latest ID (Greatest number) and was wondering what the easiest method of doing this was in python ?

Answer (score 2):

how about

`largest_id = max(int(line.split()[0][1:]) for line in output.split("\n")[5::2])`

if the output is always sorted, then

`largest_id = int(output.split('\n')[-2].split()[0][1:])`

more educatively :

```
lines = output.split('\n')
second_to_last_line = lines[-2]
splitted_by_whitespace = second_to_last_line.split()
first_non_whitespace_blob = splitted_by_whitespace[0]
id_string_ignoring_the_column_char = first_non_whitespace_blob[1:]
id = int(id_string_ignoring_the_column_char)
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks for breaking it down. The only issue I'm seeing is that this line; second_to_last_line = lines[-2] is picking up the second line down rather than the second to last line. [-4] seemed to get it going. THANK YOU!

Comment: great. happy to help. you may accept if it worked :p

Answer (score 0):

If the output is always sorted, then read each line into a list, get the second to last entry in the list, and discard the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better thake the value with shell.

```
your_command | grep -Eo '^\|[0-9]+'| cut -d "|" -f2 | sort | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regex because it looks like the ID is a 3 digit (or more) number preceded by the pipe (|) character.

This should do it:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=\|)\d{,3}')
m = regex.findall(text)
max(m)
```

Answer (score -1):

---

```html
data="..." #// Load Your Shell output
l=[]
Output=""
MaxID=0
for a in data.split("\n"):
  id=a.split()[0][1:]
  l.append(id)
  if max(l)==id:
    Output=a
    MaxID=id
print MaxID,Output
```

##

Answer (score -1):

Also you can do it using sort command in shell.

```
your_command | awk '{print $1}' | sort | tail -n1
```